# Remove related entity from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an MVC5 Code First EF6 application with the following models (simplified for the sake of this question)

```cs
public class AllocationHeader : IObjectWithState 
{
     private ICollection<AllocationLabourLine> _Labour { get; set; }
     public AllocationHeader()
     {
        _Labour = new List<AllocationLabourLine>();
     }
     public virtual ICollection<AllocationLabourLine> Labour
     {
        get { return _Labour; }
        set { _Labour = value; }
     }
}
public class AllocationLabourLine : IObjectWithState {}
```

Each AllocationHeader will have multiple AllocationLabourLines ... I've removed all other properties as I don't think they are relevant to the issue.

On my create page I create an AllocaitonHeader with a predefined number of AllocationLabourLines and return the model to the view.

```cs
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var allocation = new AllocationHeader() { AllocationDate = DateTime.Now.Date };
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            allocation.Labour.Add(new AllocationLabourLine());
        }
        GetJobs(null);
        return View(allocation);
    }
```

When the model is posted back I process through the Labour entries within the Allocation and attempt to remove any of the pre generated ones that do not contain an EmployName, these are ones that are not being used.

```cs
// validate labour
var labourDel = new List<AllocationLabourLine>();

foreach (var l in entity.Labour)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(l.EmployeeName))
    {
        // set entity to be removed as we cannot remove from collection during the foreach
        labourDel.Add(l);
    }
}
// remove items from collection
labourDel.ForEach(l => entity.Labour.Remove(l));
```

If there are errors within the ModelState and we have to return the updated model to the page, the wrong values are being used.

So if this was the data entry

**Name**

- 1
- (empty)
- 2
- 3

The returned data now looks like this, the last line is being dropped and not the second

**Name**

- 1
- (empty)
- 2

If I update the Validate Labour function to remove the labour entries from ModelState like so

```cs
// validate labour
var labourDel = new List<AllocationLabourLine>();
var count = 0;

foreach (var l in entity.Labour)
{
    var key = string.Format("Labour[{0}]", count);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(l.EmployeeName))
    {
        // set entity to be removed as we cannot remove from collection during the foreach
        labourDel.Add(l);
        // remove from ModelState
        ModelState.Keys.Where(x => x.Contains(key)).ToList().ForEach(x => ModelState.Remove(x));
    }
    count++;
}
// remove items from collection
labourDel.ForEach(l => entity.Labour.Remove(l));
```

But now the results look like this, which are still not desired, we should maintain the Names (1,2,3)

**Name**

- 1
- 2
- 2

Any ideas on how I can remove the blank labour entry from the collection and maintain the correct values.

NOTE: This data is not saved to the DB at this point, we are still on the create page.

**EDIT:** Added in the count++; code that I had left out but was in my application code.

Comment: NOTE: I know I can use ModelState.Clear() which would fix the issue on hand but that presents another one where the ModelState Validation Errors are no longer passed back to the page.

Comment: In your 2nd attempt `var key = string.Format("Labour[{0}]", count);`, `key` will always be the same as you're not incrementing `count`

Comment: @artm I am incrementing the count. There is a bit more that goes on in that function to do with setting some other field values so I trimmed it down to the relevant parts for the question.

Seems I left out the line that does the increment.

Comment: Can you try your first attempt with an index? i.e. instead of adding labours to your temp array, have an integer array and use entity.Labour.RemoveAt

Comment: @artm just tried your suggestion and it gives the same result as original first attempt 
1
 (empty)
2

Comment: Try using except like var newList= entity.labour.except(LabourDel).ToList();